# iOS Swift Facing issue on data transfer over CBL2CAPChannel

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, l2cap

1. From central i am able to connect with Peripheral device and able to read the GATT data.
2. Once peripheral connected i am opening the L2CAPChannel from central, which established successfully(logs i can see in Hercules Simulator).
3. When i am sending data from central to peripheral(hardware) it's sent successfully.
4. 2nd time when i am sending data getting **SocketStream write error [0x0]: 1 22**
5. 3rd time again when i hit l2CapChannel.outputStream.write it is not call stream delegate method with self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable false every time.
6. Also when peripheral (Hardware) send any data to central, my stream delegate method not called.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I am ble to fix the issue, as i was opening L2CAPChannel on button click, but i did it on didUpdate char**, It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to `.open()` your streams. It could be that you're closing the output stream after writing the first response and then trying to write it again.